# RemoteServiceServlet with spring autowired gives nullpointerexception

Tags: spring, gwt, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using GWT with Spring. I encountered the problem of using an `@Autowired` bean in a `RemoteServiceServlet`. For some reason this doesn't work automatically and I need to use `@Configurable` to get this working. I followed [this approach](http://blog.maxmatveev.com/2011/05/spring-beans-and-annotations-in-servlet.html) but I still get a `NullPointerException` for the `@Autowired` bean:

```
@Configurable
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public class AServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements AService {

    @Autowired
    private IABean aBean;

    @Override
    public void aMethodFromAService(Args arg[]) {
        aBean.aMethodOfABean(); // this gives a NullPointerException
    }
}

@Component
public class ABean implements IABean {
    ...
}
```

Any guidance in what is going on? Any extra information I need to provide?

Comment: where/how do you declare your ABean in Spring? XML or annotation?

Comment: annotation, edited original post

Comment: do you have <context:component-scan base-package="..." /> in application context file in order to make ABean a candidate for injection.

Comment: yes, and I used several @autowired before with success. It's the RemoteServiceServlet with GWT that causes the problem somehow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933778/why-doesnt-just-autowiring-a-field-in-a-gwt-servlet-in-spring-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mitosome.blogspot.be/2011/01/injecting-spring-beans-into-gwt.html

Thanks Alexander for putting me in the right direction

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

You found a workable solution, but just for the record and we have it working as follows:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet 
                           implements MyService, ServletContextAware
{
    @Autowired private transient SomeService someService;
    ....
}
```

and

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>
```

The `SomeService` is a completely vanilla XML-defined bean. Perhaps that or `...implements ServletContextAware` makes a difference.

Cheers,